# How to find kernel 4.19.23 commit hash?

Tags: linux, git, linux-kernel

I searched git log for 4.19 release, but could not find 4.19.23 commit hash, how can I find it?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for [linus torvalds](https://github.com/torvalds/linux) [linux:v4.19](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/v4.19) - or the more official (same one) from [git.kernel.org/torvalds/linux:v4.19](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tag/?h=v4.19) tree? What distro are you looking at and which maintainer?

Answer (score 2):

Annotated tags have their own id's, to chase a tag to an underlying commit you can use [the `^{commit}` syntax or the equivalent `^0` chase-no-parents](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrevgtltngtemegemHEADv1510em),

```
git rev-parse v4.19.23^{commit}       # for publication
```

or

```
git rev-parse v4.19.23^0              # for actual use
```

Answer (score 1):

From: [kernel:v4.19.23/Changelog](http://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/ChangeLog-4.19.23):

```
commit 67d52fae61c152a68924d94dcf0c569a96fa2f5d
Author: Greg Kroah-Hartman <gregkh@linuxfoundation.org>
Date:   Fri Feb 15 09:09:54 2019 +0100

    Linux 4.19.23
```

which references: `https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tag/?h=v4.19.23` ( [more](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tag/?h=v4.19.23) )

Answer (score 0):

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/log/?h=v4.19.23

The tagged commit is [67d52fae61c152a68924d94dcf0c569a96fa2f5d](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?h=v4.19.23&id=67d52fae61c152a68924d94dcf0c569a96fa2f5d).